# Azure AD B2C - Customize Ocean Blue template's Button Color

Tags: html, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to Azure so apologies if I missed something.

I was playing around with the Azure AD B2C Login screen. I like the Ocean Blue template for my login page. Its a simple page

[image]

I wanted to change only the color of the button from blue to green.

I know we can do that by creating a custom [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#create-an-azure-blob-storage-account) , and [here](https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/03/23/creating-custom-login-page-in-azure-ad-b2c/) and host it after enabling CORS. I Was wondering if there was an easier way to configure the button's color directly through the Azure Dashboard.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: AFAIK, there is **no way** to configure the button's color directly through the Azure Dashboard other than using custom template

Answer (score 0):

These are the built in template which won't allow to change only button color directly. Only way to customize the button in this case is using html template in Azure AD B2C.